# InstanceType and NTSecurityDescriptor attributes

Tags: ldap

I am new to ldap.

I am trying to create an AD user from Apache Directory Studio, but it needs the"NTSecurityDescriptor" attribute.

But I can't see the NTSecurityDescriptor attribute on Apache Directory Studio, nor from Softerra LDAP Browser.

Thanks in advance.